# Matching radio button selection with nested Array content in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

**UPDATE 6-25-2014**

Any insight would be appreciated!

**UPDATE 6-21-2014**

I tried to make the radio variables, global so the 'if block' in the 'answerFwd' function could be compared to the correctAnswer Array, but that didn't work!

**UPDATE 6-16-2014**
**ADDED [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/718BkQns/QpXen/3/)**

I am building a [quiz](http://dynamicquiz.aortiz.info) and creating an array of radio buttons dynamically, and would like to match the selected button with the correct answer I have established in the question array.

html

```
<div id="responses">
 <input type="radio" name="choices" class="radioButtons" value="0" id="choice0">
 <div id="c0" class="choiceText">The Observers</div>
 <input type="radio" name="choices" class="radioButtons" value="1" id="choice1">
 <div id="c1" class="choiceText">The Watchers </div>
 <input type="radio" name="choices" class="radioButtons" value="2" id="choice2">
 <div id="c2" class="choiceText">The Sentinels</div>
 <input type="radio" name="choices" class="radioButtons" value="3" id="choice3">
 <div id="c3" class="choiceText">The Oa</div>
</div>
```

questions:

```
var allQuestions = [{
"question": "Who was Luke's wingman in the battle at Hoth?",
"choices": ["Dak", "Biggs", "Wedge", "fx-7"],
"correctAnswer": 0 }, {
"question": "What is the name of Darth Vader's flag ship?",
"choices": ["The Avenger", "Devastator ", "Conquest", "The Executor"],
"correctAnswer": 3 },{},{} //other questions];


var item = allQuestions[0];

var currentQuestion = 0;

var playersScore = 0;
```

//function which creates the buttons

```
 function createRadioButtonFromArray(array) {
  var len = array.length;
  var responses = document.getElementById("responses"); 
  responses.innerHTML = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    radio = document.createElement("input"); //Updated 6-21-2014 removed 'var'
    radio.type = "radio";
    radio.name = "choices";
    radio.className = "radioButtons";
    radio.value = i;
    radio.id = "choice" + i;
    ar radioText = document.createElement("div");
    radioText.id = "c" + i;
    radioText.className = "choiceText";
    radioText.innerHTML = array[i];

    responses.appendChild(radio);
    responses.appendChild(radioText);
  }
}

function answerFwd() {
   var answerOutput = " ";
   var itemAnswers = allQuestions;

   var playerTally = 0; //Updated 6-9-2014
   var playerFeedback = " "; //Updated 6-9-2014
   var playerMessage = document.getElementById("playerMessage"); //Updated 6-9-2014

   if (currentAnswer <= itemAnswers.length) {
       currentAnswer++;
   }

   createRadioButtonFromArray(itemAnswers[currentQuestion].choices);
```

*** Updated 6-9-2014 I am stumped; This doesn't work but I was encouraged I got a score tally on the page! Am I comparing the elements correctly? Updated 6-21-2014 This reversed the gain, where I had the tally render on the screen***

```
   if (itemAnswers.correctAnswer === responses.id) { //Updated 6-21-2014
    playerTally += 1;
    playerFeedback += "<h5>" + playerTally + "</h5> <br/>";
    playerMessage.innerHTML = playerFeedback;
   }

}
```

Comment: Can anyone add any insight?

Comment: Put your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Would you consider using jQuery? it will help you manipulating DOM much more easier and effective.

Comment: I would but am trying to learn vanilla js first, because I'd like to see all the loops and such which jQuery simplifies...
Thanks!

Comment: @ super24 - Good idea!
http://jsfiddle.net/718BkQns/QpXen/3/

Answer (score 0):

At first I tried to debug this but had trouble finding where the error was coming from.

One thing I noticed was `currentAnswer` variable was only being set once. *(when it was declared)*

Another thing that would make this cleaner is storing each response to each question as a property of the questions object.

**For example:** `{"question": "What is the registry of the Starship Reliant?","choices": ["NX-01", "NCC-1864", "NCC-1701", "NCC-2000"],"correctAnswer": 1,"selectedAnswer": 0}`

---

This is a good example of why you may want to use object oriented programming. You can keep the global namespace clean, while also having tighter control over your variables.

I put together this [**Quiz Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/vVN5D/2/) using some object oriented principles:

**JavaScript**

```
var Quiz = function(questions) {
    this.questions = questions;

    this.$template = {
        "header": document.querySelector(".question"),
        "options": document.querySelector(".question-choices")
    };

    this.init();
}

Quiz.prototype = {
    "init": function() {
        this.question = 0;

        this.generateQuestion();
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    //gets called when this.question == this.questions.length, calculates a score percentage and alerts it
    "score": function() {
        var correctCount = 0;

        this.questions.forEach(function(question){
            if ( (question.selectedAnswer || -1) === question.correctAnswer ) correctCount += 1
        })

        alert("Score: " + ((correctCount / this.questions.length) * 100) + "%")
    },
    //Gets called during initialization, and also after a nav button is pressed, loads the question and shows the choices
    "generateQuestion": function() {
        var question = this.questions[this.question];

        this.$template.header.innerHTML = question.question;
        this.$template.options.innerHTML = "";
        question.choices.forEach(this.createRadio.bind(this));
    },
    //Binds the previous, and next event handlers, to navigate through the questions
    "bindEvents": function() {
        var _this = this,
            $nextBtn = document.querySelector(".question-navigation--next"),
            $prevBtn = document.querySelector(".question-navigation--prev");

        $nextBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            //Go to the next question
            _this.question++;

            if ( _this.question == _this.questions.length ) {
                _this.score();
            } else {
                _this.generateQuestion();
            }
        });

        $prevBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            _this.question--;

            if ( _this.question <= 0 ) _this.question = 0

            _this.generateQuestion();
        });
    },
    //Create each individual radio button, is callback in a forEach loop
    "createRadio": function(choice, index) {
        var question = this.questions[this.question];

        var radio = document.createElement("input");
        radio.type = "radio";
        radio.name = "options";
        radio.id = "option-"+index;

        if ( question.selectedAnswer === index ) {
            radio.checked = true;
        }

        radio.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            question.selectedAnswer = index;
        })

        var radioText = document.createElement("label");
        radioText.setAttribute("for", "option-"+index)
        radioText.innerHTML = choice;

        radioText.insertBefore(radio, radioText.firstChild);
        this.$template.options.appendChild(radioText);
    }
}

var q = new Quiz(allQuestions)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'll give it a try when I get a chance!

Comment: Looks pretty interesting (i.e. OOP principles and such, seems very concise), but could you point me in the right direction in regards to matching the radio button selection and the answer in the array, so I can ultimately post a counter with each correct answer?

Comment: You could create a new function called `calculateScore` and have it output the total correct answers, and total answer count as an object. Then you could use that object to display the running total everytime `generateQuestion` is called. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vVN5D/5/